# Reload table view when receive notification

Tags: ios6.1

I have a view controller based `UITableViewController`, I want to reload the table view when receive update notification:

```
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateApStatus:) name:@"UpdateApStatus" object:nil];
    }


- (void)updateApStatus{
    NSLog(@"......updateApStatus......");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And I post notification in other class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateApStatus" object:self];
```

The error is :

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MenuViewController updateApStatus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb25bf80'
```

It seems like i can not access `self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ":" from `updateApStatus`. You will only use a colon if the function has parameters which is not so in your case. Therefore adding the colon is a different selector completely which is why it is unrecognized.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateApStatus) name:@"UpdateApStatus" object:nil];
```